# How to dynamically create columns in a tablelayout?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to get an understanding of how to dynamically add columns and rows to a tablelayout.

I have this simple example.  However, it only shows the first column when ran.

Can someone tell me what is missing in order to display four columns instead of one?

```
package com.apollo.testtablelayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestTableLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    String col1;
    String col2;
    String col3;
    String col4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

        for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++) {

            col1 = "(" + x + ") Column 1";
            col2 = "(" + x + ") Column 2";
            col3 = "(" + x + ") Column 3";
            col4 = "(" + x + ") Column 4";

            TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);

            TextView column1 = new TextView(this);
            TextView column2 = new TextView(this);
            TextView column3 = new TextView(this);
            TextView column4 = new TextView(this);

            column1.setText(col1);

            newRow.addView(column1);
            newRow.addView(column2);
            newRow.addView(column3);
            newRow.addView(column4);

            tl.addView(newRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the setText for each of the columns text

```
column1.setText(col1); 
column2.setText(col2); 
column3.setText(col3); 
column4.setText(col4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that each column needs new TableLayout.LayoutParams() as well, that was the mistake I made trying to add a more complex view to a table layout.

```
newRow.addView(view, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
```